# use getTableFilterState in Filament Resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

#### Description

In this code, in BadgeColumn I use`$this->getTableFilterState('created_at')['date']`to get filter data but this show error

like

> Using $this when not in object context

**This is my PayRollResource.php**

```
public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
        return $table
            ->query(Employee::active()->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date))
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('name')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('email')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('phone')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('unique_id')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('salary'),
                TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
                BadgeColumn::make('payroll_status')
                    ->label("PayRoll Status")
                    ->colors([
                        'success' => static fn ($state): bool => $state == 'Paid',
                        'danger' => static fn ($state): bool => $state == 'Unpaid',
                    ])
                    ->getStateUsing(function (Employee $record) {
                        return $record->payrollStatus($this->getTableFilterState('created_at')['date']);
              
                    }),
                TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
            ])
            ->filters([
                Filter::make('created_at')
                    ->form([
                        DatePicker::make('date'),
                    ])

                    ->indicateUsing(function (array $data): array {
                        $indicators = [];
                        if ($data['date']) {
                            $indicators['date'] = 'Date ' . Carbon::parse($data['date'])->toFormattedDateString();
                        }
                        return $indicators;
                    }),

            ])
```

**This is my Payroll page**

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Pages\ViewEmployee;
use App\Models\Employee;
use BezhanSalleh\FilamentShield\Traits\HasPageShield;
use Filament\Pages\Page;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Filament\Tables\Filters\Filter;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn;
use Filament\Tables\Contracts\HasTable;
use Filament\Forms\Components\DatePicker;
use Filament\Tables\Concerns\InteractsWithTable;
use Filament\Tables\Actions\Action as ActionsAction;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\BadgeColumn;

class Payroll extends Page implements HasTable
{
    use InteractsWithTable, HasPageShield;
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-banknotes';

    protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.payroll';

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

        return $table
            ->query(Employee::active()->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date))
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('name')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('email')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('phone')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('unique_id')
                    ->searchable(),
                TextColumn::make('salary'),
                TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
                BadgeColumn::make('payroll_status')
                    ->label("PayRoll Status")
                    ->colors([
                        'success' => static fn ($state): bool => $state == 'Paid',
                        'danger' => static fn ($state): bool => $state == 'Unpaid',
                    ])
                    ->getStateUsing(function (Employee $record) {
                        return $record->payrollStatus($this->getTableFilterState('created_at')['date']);
                    }),

                TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
            ])
            ->filters([
                Filter::make('created_at')
                    ->form([
                        DatePicker::make('date'),
                    ])

                    ->indicateUsing(function (array $data): array {
                        $indicators = [];
                        if ($data['date']) {
                            $indicators['date'] = 'Date ' . Carbon::parse($data['date'])->toFormattedDateString();
                        }
                        return $indicators;
                    }),
            ])
            ->actions([
                ActionsAction::make('View')
                    ->color('success')
                    ->icon('heroicon-o-banknotes')
                    ->url(function (Employee $record): string {
                        return route('payroll.view', [$record->id, 'date' => $this->getTableFilterState('created_at')['date']]);
                    })
            ])
            ->bulkActions([]);
    }
}
```

**In this page `$this->getTableFilterState` is work fine. I want to change this custom page into filament resource but in default resource page `$this->getTableFilterState` is not work! Why this happen? any advice for this please**

**I want to use `$this->getTableFilterState` on Filament resource page**

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are experiencing is because `$this->getTableFilterState` is not available in the default Filament resource pages. It appears that you have a custom Filament page that is using this method but, when you use the default resource page, it doesn't work because the method is not available in that context.

If you want to use `$this->getTableFilterState` or similar functionality in a Filament resource page, you will need to create a custom resource page. Here's a basic example of how you can create a custom resource page with the desired functionality:

```
php artisan filament:resource PageName

use Filament\Resource;

class PageName extends Resource
{
    public static $icon = 'heroicon-o-banknotes';

    public $table = \App\Filament\Tables\YourCustomTable::class;

    public function table($table)
    {
        // Customize your table here
        return $table;
    }
}

use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Filament\Tables\Concerns\InteractsWithTable;

class YourCustomTable extends Table
{
    use InteractsWithTable;

    public function columns()
    {
        // Define your table columns
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        // Define your table filters
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        // Define your table actions
    }

    // Define your custom methods and logic, including the use of $this->getTableFilterState
}
```